# Django graphql graphene removing redundant queries from return value

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

The last few days I have read up on so much graphql that I can't see the trees from the forest anymore.

The results that this person got in the beginning is almost exactly what I want (his problem, not his solution), but it seems that a lot of the code is deprecated and I can't seem to get it working: [link](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/537)

I have a bunch of containers that I return. All the containers have the amounts for every day in them. I only want to return the amounts of a certain day.

At the moment, I do return these results (day), but all the other results (days) also return with a Null value.

Current behavior:

```
{
  "data": {
    "listProductcontainers": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "productid": {
          "productid": "CBG2",
          "processedstockamountsSet": [
            {
              "timeStampID": {
                "id": "2"
              },
              "id": "77745",
              "prodName": {
                "productid": "CBG2"
              }
            },
            {
              "timeStampID": null,   <--------
              "id": "89645",
              "prodName": {
                "productid": "CBG2"
              }
            },
            {
              "timeStampID": null,   <--------
              "id": "89848",
              "prodName": {
                "productid": "CBG2"
              }
            },

// ...
```

Requested behavior:  (All values with 'Null' should not return)

```
{
  "data": {
    "listProductcontainers": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "productid": {
          "productid": "CBG2",
          "processedstockamountsSet": [
            {
              "timeStampID": {
                "id": "2"
              }
```

My query that I am running looks like this:

```
query{
  listProductcontainers{
    id
    productid{
      productid
      processedstockamountsSet{
        timeStampID(id:2){
          id
        }
        id
        prodName{
          productid
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the relevant code for the results:

```
class TimeStampType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = TimeStamp

class ProcessedStockAmountsType(DjangoObjectType):
    timeStampID = graphene.Field(TimeStampType, id=graphene.Int())
    class Meta:
        model = ProcessedStockAmounts 

    def resolve_timeStampID(self, info, **kwargs):
        id = kwargs.get('id')
        if self.timeStampID.id == id:
            return self.timeStampID

class ProductcontainersType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Productcontainers 

class ProductlistType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Productlist 

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    list_productcontainers = graphene.List(ProductcontainersType)

    def resolve_list_productcontainers(self, context, **kwargs):
        return Productcontainers.objects.all()
```

I have read almost everything in graphene by now, but if you even have a link that mirrors what I want to do I would really appreciate it.

My final option is to make two calls where I get all the container ids, and another call where I get all the amounts (with container id) for a certain date, and with 2 for loops I just add the amounts into the corresponding container... :(